# how to create index from gremlin console in janusgraph

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

i tried writing script for creating index but then it is throeing an exception during buildCompositeIndex() function the error that is showing is "org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Wrote claim for id block [1301, 1351) in PT0.318886S => too slow,threshold is: PT0.3S". but tried increasing the time in my graph configuration still it is giving this error not sure what is the issue ,then i tried to create index from gremlin console but the index is getting created but the status of the index is shoeing as installed ,is there any way that can solve this issue.

this is what i tried from gremlin console :

```
mgmt=graphname.openManagement() 
PropertyKey propertyName = mgmt.getPropertyKey("name"); mgmt.buildIndex("myIndex",Vertex.class).addKey(mgmt.getPropertyKey("name")).indexOnly(mgmt.getVertxLabel("Column")).buildCompositeIndex(); 
mgmt.commit();
```

the status here is giving installed i know that first the status is going to installed then registered and then enabled but here in my case it is not updating when i try creating it from console.

then i wrote a script to create index :

```
mgmt=graphname.openManagement()
PropertyKey propertyName = mgmt.getPropertyKey("name");
mgmt.buildIndex("myIndex", Vertex.class).addKey(mgmt.getPropertyKey("name")).indexOnly(mgmt.getVertexLabel("Column")).buildCompositeIndex();
mgmt.commit();
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, indexName).call();
mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex(indexName), SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX).get();
mgmt.commit();
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, indexName).status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED, SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call();           
graph.close();
```

here at the time of buildCompositeIndex() function is is throwing error TemporaryBackendException is there any issue with my code or beacuse of my laptop memory issue

Comment: We faced the same issue, You need to create an index before creating any vertices.